# Open database of image labels

Tags: image, label

I'm working on a program which needs a large amount of images, with keywords describing the images and the things they contain.

Now, I know that Google Image Labeler exists to help Google create such a database, to help boost their image search. I'm wondering if there is any such database that I can use, either Google's or someone else's.

I'm assuming that if there is, it might cost some kind of license (or it might only be accessible by using an online api). Both of those options are fine, I'm just looking for anything available for now.

**Edit:** I think this may have been unclear, I'm not talking about a database to store things in, I'm talking about access to a database already filled with images and their keywords. I basically need a few thousand images, plus words that describe them, and I'm wondering if such a resource already exists, or if I have to create it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about a photography application, like [Google Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/)? It may not be the most obvious solution, but it fits the criteria as you describe them.

Comment: I'm not sure how this applies to my question, unless there are features of Picasa that I don't know about. (I edited my question to make it clearer, since I think I may have misexplained what it was that I wanted).

Answer (score 0):

I think Flickr actually offers such an API that allows you to retrieve images by color or tag.
plus you can find a lot of Creative commons images on Flickr, so licensing wouldn't be an issue.